# Best way to fix this bad shading after applying boolean?

Tags: shaders, boolean-modifier

I applied a boolean on a cylinder to try and make a screw and got this weird shading.

[image]

[image]

First I tried deleting all the faces on the ngon and adding helper edges on the inner hexagon and filling it all up but that seemed like overkill and didn't really fix it.

[image]

Then I remembered the weighted normals modifier could help and it did for the most part but it messed up the interior of the hexagon.

[image]

Normals are correct and scale is applied. So I was just wondering what is the best way to fix something like this? Is there a specific technique that works best here? Any helpful tips would be great.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Booleans usually create bad topology and should be avoided if possible imho, especially if the ngons are created on non-planar surfaces. can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com.

Comment: Yeah, I know the topology that results from booleans isn't great but I'm sure there are ways to make it better. I uploaded my file here [https://blend-exchange.com/b/ypeKPV5V](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ypeKPV5V). The screws in question are on the left side. This is result with weighted normals which made it look way better from afar but not if you zoom in close on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of Boolean modifiers usually entails doing some manual fixes to get good topology, but in your case it is easier to fix. The fastest way would be to select those big n-gons and press <kbd>I</kbd> to [Inset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html#inset-faces) a small amount and then inset again a bigger amount. Then you can inset once for the deeper face. See the highlighted in orange Edge Loops that got added from the Inset operation:

[image]

Comment: Wow that's so much easier than I thought it would be. I just tried and it looks so much better now. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: you're welcome! only disadvantage of that n-gon is that you can't add a subdivision to the object without causing a mess. but you can easily solve it quickly by deleting the n-gon and then selecting both edge loops and going to *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops* to get [this result](https://snipboard.io/EzTqM9.jpg) which can then be applied a subdivision modifier or better model it again with prettier quads. then don't forget to inset the back and center of the deep hole as well if you plan to add a subdivision.

Comment: Awesome, that's good to know. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks again for the help.